# Custom Menu Item on ActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-menu

I am now having a problem with using "android:actionLayout" in menu.

I have used this and worked in some of my previous project but now i have no idea what is going on.

When i typed

```
android:title="@string/menu_notifications"
android:actionLayout="@layout/menu_notification"
```

**Every icon in actionBar in my application changed to Text.**

I tried a lot of things nothing have worked. I have no clue what is happening.

Please some advice / idea?

**EDIT:
menu_notification.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:text="TEST"
android:textSize="20dp"
android:textColor="#F00"
/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**EDIT 2:**

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure "menu_notification" is xml

Comment: What the version of OS you tested?

Comment: can you post your xml

Comment: @MSS I made edit with my xml

Comment: @deathember i am testing this on version 4.2.2

Answer (score 0):

change  menu_notification.xml as,

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:text="TEST"
    android:textSize="20dp"
  android:textColor="#F00"
 />
```

and main.xml,

```
     <item
     android:id="@+id/log_out"
      android:actionLayout="@layout/menu_notification"
    android:icon="@drawable/power"

 android:showAsAction="always"
/>
```

then ,

```
 @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
TextView txtview=(TextView )menu.findItem(R.id.log_out).getActionView();
//do remaining stuff here
```

}

Comment: Not working, the same only text 'Notifications' appears.